# 'equal' is not defined : Ember-qunit does not seem to be importing

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, ember-cli, qunit

It appears the Qunit test methods aren't available even though I'm pretty sure I am importing them correctly.

I get the following errors:

```
unit/models/friend-test.js: line 11, col 3, 'ok' is not defined.
unit/models/friend-test.js: line 17, col 3, 'equal' is not defined.
unit/models/friend-test.js: line 23, col 3, 'equal' is not defined.
unit/models/friend-test.js: line 31, col 3, 'equal' is not defined.
unit/models/friend-test.js: line 32, col 3, 'equal' is not defined.
```

I have this test file `unit/models/friend-test`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { moduleForModel,  test } from 'ember-qunit';


moduleForModel('friend', 'Friend', {
  needs: ['model:article']
});

test('it exists', function() {
  var model = this.subject();
  ok(model);
});

test('fullName concats first and last name', function() {
  var model = this.subject({firstName: 'Syd', lastName: 'Barrett'});

  equal(model.get('fullName'), 'Syd Barrett');

  Ember.run(function() {
    model.set('firstName', 'Geddy');
  });

  equal(model.get('fullName'), 'Geddy Barrett', 'Updates fullName');
});

test('articles relationship', function() {
  var klass  = this.subject({}).constructor;

  var relationship = Ember.get(klass, 'relationshipsByName').get('articles');

  equal(relationship.key, 'articles');
  equal(relationship.kind, 'hasMany');
});
```

I'm working through "[Ember CLI 101](https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101)"

Comment: Seems like it'd have to be `test.ok`, `test.equal`, etc, but I'm just guessing from first principles because I'm unfamiliar with Ember (and qunit).

Comment: @Pointy Prefixing with `test` did clear the errors. Thanks. The example code doesn't include these prefixes, though, I'm curious how they could omit them. Thank you, though, at least I can proceed.

Comment: Actually, although the errors mentioned above clear after prefixing the method calls with `test`, the test still fails, albeit with a different message: `ember_qunit.test.ok is not a function`

Comment: Well all I (think I) know is that an `import` like that can't make global symbols like "ok" and "equals" just appear in the namespace.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Still figuring this framework out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Author here! Sorry about it, I actually need to update the code since on the latest release the syntax for tests changed to match the upcoming version of QUNit.

Now to use: `equal`, `ok` and the other QUnit's assertions, we have to do it through a param called assert in the callback function passed to test:
`test('foo', function(assert){ assert.ok(true) }`. I'll send a book update tonight to fix this :), in the meantime, the following should work:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { moduleForModel,  test } from 'ember-qunit';


moduleForModel('friend', 'Friend', {
  needs: ['model:article']
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var model = this.subject();
  assert.ok(model);
});

test('fullName concats first and last name', function(assert) {
  var model = this.subject({firstName: 'Syd', lastName: 'Barrett'});

  equal(model.get('fullName'), 'Syd Barrett');

  Ember.run(function(assert) {
    model.set('firstName', 'Geddy');
  });

  assert.equal(model.get('fullName'), 'Geddy Barrett', 'Updates fullName');
});

test('articles relationship', function(assert) {
  var klass  = this.subject({}).constructor;

  var relationship = Ember.get(klass, 'relationshipsByName').get('articles');

  assert.equal(relationship.key, 'articles');
  assert.equal(relationship.kind, 'hasMany');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in tests/helpers/start-app.js.  You should see something like:

```
Ember.run(function() {
    registerAcceptanceTestHelpers();
    application = Application.create(attributes);
    application.setupForTesting();
    application.injectTestHelpers();
  });
```

This injects the test helpers into the application global scope.

Comment: All those functions are there with the exception of `registerAcceptanceTestHelpers()`, which comes up as `undefined`

Comment: That is from one of the ember-cli add ons.  You do not need that one.